# Changed ownership in /usr/lib in Mint

Tags: linux, permissions, linux-mint

So this was really stupid..

I am using Linux Mint 14 Cinnamon 64-bit.
I mistakely changed the ownership of the entire /usr/lib to my own user (I actually meant to change the ownership of one subdirectory inside it).
I did this by executing:

```
sudo chown -R $USER .
```

The problem was I couldn't even undo it, because executing sudo after that resulted with an error:

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by gid 10, should be 0
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
```

What I did then is restart Mint in recovery mode, mount the drive in write-mode, started the shell as root, and changed the ownership back to root.

HOWEVER, after restarting Mint in normal mode, a couple of things don't work:

1. Network - doesn't work at all. And if I open the network settings I get an error:

   "The system network services are not compatible with this version."

   and the only setting that is available is "Network proxy". The network connections lists (both wired and wireless) are completely empty.
2. The speakers don't work.

So now I'm wondering two things:

1. is there anything else that isn't working that I don't know yet, and
2. is there's anything I can do at this point without reinstalling the OS. It's relatively newly installed, so it won't be a huge pain, but still will waste a good part of my day. On the other hand, I'd rather reinstall if I can't be sure I'll have a reliably working system..
   So what is the recommended move at this point?

Comment: What commands did you use to change the ownership back to root? Also, could you post the output of `ls -la /usr/lib`?